# Parse Excel File stored in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, development

I want to parse an Excel file which is stored in a document library in SharePoint Online, perform calculations on the data and push the final results to Dynamics 365 / CDS. Using Microsoft flow might be a possibility, but there would still be coding left to do.

Parsing an Excel file in C# is possible with Microsoft Interop assemblies. Would it be possible to deploy code which uses Interop assemblies to SharePoint Online and execute the code on an Excel file in SharePoint (e.g. select the Excel file in SharePoint Online, push a button and execute the code)?

If not, what other possibilities are there to execute custom code, parse data and move it around different applications in Microsoft 365?